# Expected spy go to have been called with [ 'stateName' ] but it was never called?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, angular-ui-router, state

This is working fine:
`spyOn($state, 'go');`

But when I execute below line its not working and giving this error:

> 'Expected spy go to have been called with [ 'stateName' ] but it was
>   never called'

```js
expect($state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('stateName'); 
describe('Home Controller Test Suite', function() {

var HomeCtrl,$rootScope, $controller, $scope, $http, $state,factory;
var baseURL = "http://localhost:8000/";
beforeEach(module("ui.router"));
beforeEach(module("rbControllers"));
beforeEach(module("ui.bootstrap"));
beforeEach(module("toggle-switch"));
beforeEach(module("ngDraggable"));
beforeEach(module("angular-loading-bar"));
beforeEach(module("ngAnimate"));
beforeEach(module("kendo.directives"));
beforeEach(module("rbApp"));
beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_ ,_$controller_,_$httpBackend_, _$state_){
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller = _$controller_;
    httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $state = _$state_;
    HomeCtrl = $controller('HomeCtrl', {'$scope': $scope, '$state': $state, 'baseURL' : baseURL, 'roobrickUiService': factory});
}));

it("Test: HomeCtrl exists or not", function() {
    expect(HomeCtrl).toBeDefined();
});

 it("Test:xxx run", function() {
    spyOn($state, 'go');
    expect($state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('stateName');
 });
});
```

Comment: Well, that's quite expected, since between the instruction where you spy on $state.go, and the instruction where you check that $state.go() has been called, there is 0 instruction. So $state.go() indeed has never been called. This test doesn't make any sense. The point of a spy is to spy, then call some function which *should* call $state.go, and to verify that $state.go indeed has been called by the function. But you're not calling any function.

Comment: @JB Nizet  
I'm very new in this unit testing thing so any help will be much appreciated, 
 so i have a function like this `$scope.goadd = function() { 
        $state.go('stateName'); 
};`

I want to test this function, but i really i'm not able to test it, and thats why took body of this function outside so that i could individually test it. But i guess its the wrong way. please help

Comment: To test that function, you need to **call** it. Between the call to spyOn() and the call to expect(). If you don't call it, you're not testing anything.

Comment: @JB Nizet            `spyOn($state, 'go').and.callThrough();
            spyOn($scope,'goadd').and.callThrough();
        $scope.goadd();
         expect($state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('stateName');
         expect($scope.goadd).toHaveBeenCalled();`

**Now the Error is: **  Expected spy go to have been called with [ 'stateName' ] but actual calls were [ 'stateName' ]. I don't know why it should have called the state but its not calling with state.